# How to make a div clickable then opens up a pannel or div using ajax on that same area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i want make a div clickable in such away that it open a new  i.e pannel or div with ajax ( without refreshing page ) for example when you click a message on your various messenger on you phone it opens up a conversation page or div or pannel or section

Comment: Whatr code have you tried so far to do this?

Comment: i have not written anything yet except the php code of the message.php page for social network site and i jst want to it make more dynamic and more advance.... for example when i click the message it opens the message in full without refreshing the page

Comment: Ok, this can be done, but we need to see SOMETHING that you have been working with to give you any help or advice.

Comment: <div class="tabbed">
<input name="tabbed" id="tabbed1" type="radio" checked>
 <section>
       <h1>
          <label for="tabbed1">New Messages</label>
        </h1>
        <div id = " the_message">i want this specific div to be clickable ..for example when i click the message it opens the message in full without refreshing the page
<?Php (php goes here)
?>
</div>
  </section>
      <input name="tabbed" id="tabbed2" type="radio">
      <section>
        <h1>
          <label for="tabbed2">Read Messages</label>
        </h1>
        <div> (this div also)
<?php  
?>
</div>
</section>
</div>

Comment: <div class="tabbed">
<input name="tabbed" id="tabbed1" type="radio" checked>
 <section>
       <h1>
          <label for="tabbed1">New Messages</label>
        </h1>
        <div id = " the_message">i want this specific div to be clickable ..for example when i click the message it opens the message in full without refreshing the page
<?Php (php goes here)
?>
</div>
  </section>
      <input name="tabbed" id="tabbed2" type="radio">
      <section>
        <h1>
          <label for="tabbed2">Read Messages</label>
        </h1>
        <div> (this div also)
<?php  
?>
</div>
</section>
</div>

Comment: Do you want the Subject to be the label for an accordion style reveal? Or do you want it to open in a dialog box, it's own window? Please be very clear and detailed.

Comment: for example when you click your message in your mail box it opens the message in full just like ..yahoo mail, google mail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/e7bp5ty7/

**HTML**

```
<div class="tabbed">
  <input name="tabbed" id="tabbed1" type="radio" checked>
  <section>
    <h1> <label for="tabbed1" data-rel="message-0">Message 1</label> </h1>
    <div id="message-0" class="message-content">
      I want this specific div to be clickable... for example when I click the message it opens the message in full without refreshing the page
    </div>
  </section>
  <input name="tabbed" id="tabbed2" type="radio">
  <section>
    <h1> <label for="tabbed2" data-rel="message-1">Message 2</label> </h1>
    <div id="message-1" class="message-content">
      Another Test message.
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.message-content {
  display: none;
  margin: 7px;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".tabbed label").click(function() {
    var mID = $(this).attr("data-rel");
    $("#" + mID).toggle("slow");
  });
});
```

By adjusting the HTML a bit, we can add a few classes and attributes to help us in the long run. We hide the message content using CSS and then when the label is clicked, we bind an event to it using JQuery. Using `.toggle()` we can Hide/Show it each time it's clicked. The `slow` just helps animate it, but can be `fast` or omitted all together.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery bind: 
 $("#your_div_id").bind("change keyup", function() {/* do something interesting here */} );

Comment: If you're going to use AJAX (in your description), you will by definition be using javascript. In pure html, you would specify <div id="myAjaxDiv" onclick="myJavaScriptFunction()"></div> The id= is included so that you can reference this specific div (id's need to be unique) and the onclick states what javascript function will be executed when you click on the div.

Comment: oh thanks,  but what function() will be perfect for what am trying to do then?......i only know " function(){ alert("this is the only funtion i know in javascript .");"

Comment: a function is javascript is specified by the phrase function yourFunctionName (arg1, arg2, etc) { javascript logic } There isn't a single 'canned' function which will automagically take the output from the get/post you send to your web server and format it into your web page. You may want to look at a book such as David Flannigan's "Javascript: The definitive guide" or Robin Nixon's "PHP, MySQL & Javascript" as places to start reading.